# Sync word custom properties with sharepoint custom properties

Tags: 2010, sharepoint-server, visual-studio, word, office-integration

I had a custom property(columm) on a sharepoint library called 'Status'.
Whenever we would save a document(.doc) on a library, word woul ask if I wanted to save the .dot template file(Even though it was read only!).

We don't want to have this prompt show every time, word souldn't ask if we want to save the .dot file. So some of my teamates thought that it was because of the 'status' property.

So I made it so that now the property is on the word docs. Now I have a doc with a custom property called "Status". But I can't seem to figure out how to make sharepoint display a word custom property on a columm.

So, how do I make a library columm that has a doc property on it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can read up on it at the following location:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/aa543341(v=office.14).aspx

SharePoint will promote values from a *.docx file into a SharePoint Library when the word custom property matches a the name of a site column in the document library.

When you make changes to site column's in the library, the changes will be demoted (updated in) the word document.

SharePoint 2010 only executes Property Promotion and Demotion of files with the matching Office Version.

Office 2010 = SharePoint 2010